Est-ce que c'est très soutenu d'omettre « pas » pour certains verbes?
J'ai rencontré par hasard ce post sur Reddit où une personne dit qu'en omettant pas pour les verbes pouvoir, cesser, oser, and savoir on donne l'impression de venir du 19e siècle.
C'est vrai? Au moins, je pensais que c'est normal voire obligatoire d'omettre pas dans le cas de pouvoir.

Omettre le pas? Je ne peux pas croire que ce soit normal, encore moins obligatoire.

Cette personne devait exprimer une impression personnelle, je ne pense pas qu'il y ait de différence sur ce point entre le 19ᵉ et le 21ᵉ.  En tous les cas l'omission n'est pas obligatoire, il me semble que cette question répond bien à ta question : Omission of pas

Par contre, avec la forme puis de la 1ère personne, le pas est effectivement malvenu. Je ne puis [nullement|aucunement] croire... is OK, Je ne puis {pas | point} croire... is not.

Dans le langage courant actuel, l'omission du "pas" paraît un peu précieuse. Ce sentiment peut faire penser à la littérature du XiXème. Toutefois, dans quelques cas, l'omission du "pas" semple plus naturelle que sa présence, par exemple dans je ne cesse d'y penser.

@Graffito Oui,je ne cesse est soutenu donc s'accorde mal avec l'omission du pas. Dans un registre courant, on dirait j'arrête pas d'y penser alors que je n'arrête d'y penser me semble encore plus inhabituel que je ne cesse pas d'y penser.

@Graffito Pour moi il semblerait que l’omission de pas marque de langage soutenu, serait plus du ressort de la  langue classique que de celle du 19ᵉ siècle. Mais bien sûr il faudrait une étude  poussée sur un corpus plus important que mes souvenirs de Molière et Racine comparés à Zola ou Hugo.

Hmm I do not at all agree that this question is a duplicate. That question is asking about the general omission of pas in the majority of cases - this question is asking whether it is mandatory to leave out pas for a specific subset of verbs. I do not find a satisfactory answer anywhere in the one reply to that question. Moreover a large portion of that answer, the majority actually, addresses the omission of ne - a separate point entirely!
